# Highest Card Game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, module

[image]So I have created this Highest Card game in python, the code runs well and the program opens. The only problem I have is that when the crads are drawn to each player it doesnt display the card number and Suit. it displays (<**main**.HC_Card Object at 0x02EB2670>;) image attacthed. Can anyone help with this ? Would be very much appreciated.

Card Module:

## The Card Module

```
import sys

class Card(object):
# A playing card
    CARDS=[ "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" ]
    SUITS=[ "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" ]
    def __init__(self, card, suit):
        self.card = card
        self.suit = suit
        
class Hand(object):
# A hand of playing cards
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
            rep = ""
            for card in self.cards:
                rep += str(card) + "; "
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep
    def clear(self):
        self.cards = []
    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)
    def give(self, card, other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)
        
class Deck(Hand):
# A deck of playing cards
    def populate(self):
        for suit in Card.SUITS:
            for card in Card.CARDS:
                self.add(Card(card, suit))
    def shuffle(self):
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
    def deal(self, hands, per_hand = 1):
        for rounds in range(per_hand):
            for hand in hands:
                if self.cards:
                    top_card = self.cards[0]
                    self.give(top_card, hand)
                else:
                    print("Deck has run out of cards. Game over.")
                    sys.exit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This is a module with classes for playing cards.")
    
#input("\nPress Enter to exit")
```

Games Module:

## Games module

```
class Player(object):
# Defines a player in a game
    def __init__(self, name, score = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + ":\t" + str(self.score)
        return rep
def askYesNo(question):
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response
def askForNumber(question, low, high):
    response = None
    while response not in range (low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("You ran this module directly (not imported).")
    #input("\nPress Enter to exit.")
```

Main Code:

```
import Cards, Games

class HC_Card(Cards.Card):
    @property
    def value(self):
        val = HC_Card.CARDS.index(self.card) + 1
        return val

class HC_Deck(Cards.Deck):
    def populate(self):
        for suit in HC_Card.SUITS:
            for card in HC_Card.CARDS:
                self.cards.append(HC_Card(card, suit))

class HC_Hand(Cards.Hand):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(HC_Hand, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + ": " + super(HC_Hand, self).__str__()
        return rep
    @property
    def total(self):
        t = 0
        for card in self.cards:
            t += card.value
        return t
 
class HC_Game(object):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.players = []
        for name in names:
            player = HC_Hand(name)
            self.players.append(player)
        self.deck = HC_Deck()
        self.deck.populate()
        self.deck.shuffle()
    
    def play(self):
        self.deck.deal(self.players, per_hand = 1)
        highestCard = 0
        highestName = ""
        for player in self.players:
            print(player)
            if player.total == highestCard:
                highestName = "Draw"
            elif player.total > highestCard:
                highestCard = player.total
                highestName = player.name
        print("\nAnd the winner is...", highestName, "With the..", highestCard, "\b.")
        
        
        for player in self.players:
            player.clear()
 
def main():
    print("\nThis is the Highest Card game...")
    print("The player with the Highest card wins.. Good Luck!\n")
    names = []
    number = Games.askForNumber("How many players? (2-7): ", low = 2, high = 8)
    print()
    i = 1
    for i in range(number):
        name = input("Enter player name: ")
        if name == "":
            names.append("Anon")
            print()
            i += 1
        else:
            names.append(name)
            print()
            #i += 1
    game = HC_Game(names)
    again = "Y"
    rounds = 0
    while again == "y" or again == "Y":
        rounds += 1
        num_cards_dealt = number * rounds
        if num_cards_dealt > 52 - number:
            game.__init__(names)
            rounds = 0
        game.play()
        again = Games.askYesNo("\nDo you want to play again? ")
        print()
    print("I hope you enjoyed the game..")
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add `__str__` function with `card` and `suit` variables under `Card` class to print out.

Code:

```
class Card(object):
    # A playing card
    CARDS = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
             "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
    SUITS = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]

    def __init__(self, card, suit):
        self.card = card
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.card} of {self.suit}"
```

Output:

```
...
How many players? (2-7): 2

Enter player name: alec
Enter player name: lluke

alec: Queen of Spades;
lluke: 9 of Diamonds;
...
```

Comment: I have added this code to my exsisting code and the program doesnt open up ?

Comment: Did u delete init function in Card object? I put … as referred previous code, pls put str function under init function as different function. All code tested, output shows it

Comment: if u have stil problem, pls mention here, I’ll put complete card class

Comment: I have added the code you suggested onto what I have and it doesnt seem to work. sorry I might have missed something. I really appreciate the help

Comment: I added all Card class, pls add it instead of old one

Comment: for some strange reason this does not work for me when I run code.. im not sure why though

Comment: Create new directory, copy your code step by step. 1. Copy all Card module code into Cards.py, 2. Copy the Game module code in Games.py. 3. Copy the Main code in main.py , run this code first without any change. Until this part, it is all ur code.. Then copy Card class that I mentioned above, instead of your Card Class. I did it now, it works..

Comment: So essentially write all my code out again with your code added ?

Comment: Thank you for your help I shall try this out and see what happens.